# Checking checkbox of another website

Tags: javascript, php

is there a way I can check a checkbox and submit a button from a website I have no access to using another website? I have tried using the attr and prop function in javascript but it doesnt work maybe becayse its on another website and I have no access on it. In short, I want to create a website where I can automatically open this website https://clec.att.com/facilitiescheck/facilities_chk.cfm and input the necessary information and then click both the checkbox and the submit button. I can dynamically send the data to the textbox but I cant check the checkbox which is a required field and submit the button.

E.g.
I have my index.php file which has a button and after I click it, it goes to the facilities check website and automatically check the checkbox and submit its button.

Thanks.

Comment: Quick answer: no you can't. It's forbidden for security reason. It if would be possible, bad things could be happening (how could you be sure a JS script is not currently opening your gmail account in an invisible iframe ?)

Comment: you can try it using `curl` though..

Comment: Single Origin Policy will prevent you.

Comment: Well actually what I said is not true... In some case you could, by sending the appropriate value by GET when redirecting the user to that page. But it depends on how the targeted website is built. In your case, you can't.

Comment: @tanmay I'm really not familiar with curl can you please send an example? Thanks.

Comment: @Scalpweb So do you mean that I cant check the checkbox using another webpage? I've been stuck with this problem quite some time now. Is there another language that would be a better fit for this problem? What I'm trying to do is, automate it so that we can use it for mass checking rather than inputing addresses one by one. Thanks,

Comment: You will not be able to do it using Javascript in a web page. A webpage cannot perform action on another webpage that is not hosted in the same domain. It's called Single Origin Policy. If you want to automate some web browsing aciton, you should use another technology. You could use nightmareJS, with NodeJS, to stick with Javascript, but it will not be running on a webpage. http://www.nightmarejs.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scalpweb

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scalpweb. I'll try using nightmarejs, But I cant find basic info or how to start with it. Can I know which applications I can use? or just your basic assumption with the approach I'll be doing. Sorry if I ask more and more but I'm not really familiar with nightmarejs. I saw that I can use python. Thanks so much. Sorry if Im asking for too much.

Comment: Hopefully the last question @Scalpweb. I've found some guides with the setup. But I just to know in front if nightmare.js is free? Thanks.

Comment: @JeyPi I mentioned `curl` since you are using php. It is a php module you can include and use to achieve things like this. With node.js, you can easily do this kind of things using `nightmare` (as mentioned in other comments) or `cheerio`

Comment: nightmare.js is completely free, yes. I used it many times, so if you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Scalpweb I found this guide, http://www.devsbytes.com/browser-automation-with-nightmarejs.html this is the only guide that is easy to understand but I still cant fully execute it. It seems like, it can only work on a linux computer. Luckily, I have an old laptop that is currently running elementary os. Can you please tell me how to install everything in order to use nightmare.js to its full extent? Thank you so much. I'm not really familiar with linux but I have some basic knowledge. I dont understand the part for the PhantomJS. I just dont know how to start or where to start. Thanks.

Comment: @Scalpweb is there another way we can chat privately about this matter? tried searching and searching on how to setup nightmarejs but didnt really found any article that will help me. All I found was you need to install nodejs with npm and phantom js. But after I tried installing it through the terminal, it wont work saying that the linux version I have is not enterprise. I also tried installing nodejs using the guide they have on their website, but I wasnt able to install phantom js after, which made me uninstall node js because I noticed that it didnt have npm included in it. Thanks so much.